# break jquery $('<div>') into separate opening and closing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several blocks like:

```
<div class="first">...</div>
<div class="second">...</div>
<div class="third">..</div>
```

I want to wrap all 3 blocks with another div.
Is there a way to split $('</div>') in two parts: <div> and </div> so I could insertBefore() the opening <div> and insertAfter() the closing </div> I could achieve it simply with html but I can't modify it in this situation

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/  and  http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 5):

Could you use '[wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)'?

```
$('div').wrapAll('<div class="new" />');
```

Comment: Thanks. wrapAll() is the way, but there can be other elements with different classes

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm understanding you correctly, but you should be able to store the elements in variables, and add the new elements to them like this.

```
var el1 = $("div")
var el2 = el.add("div");
var el3 = el2.add("div");
```

Comment: That's the other way but I need different solution as  there may be 100 elements with different attributes and content

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to nest the elements within each other, or wrap the elements in a containing div?

Comment: wrap the elements with containting div. I've changed the markup so you could see that there can be any elements

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't create the container in the markup, and just add the DIV elements to it?

Comment: Yes there is a specific situation in which I have to use Js